# Jquery Multi-select

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I am using jquery multiselect plugin http://wilkerlucio.github.com/jquery-multiselect/

Provided fiddle select correctly the items with mouse, but If I/Someone download the code and run the provided example then it works fine with keyboard keys but with mouse only last one can be selected.

Is any/some thing(s) is missing in package but available in fiddle?

Comment: Even i am having the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: I was using the latest min js file "jquery.multiselect.0.1.9.min.js" but the mouse over fixes working fine in "jquery.multiselect.0.1.7.min.js" package file. So I integrate the 1.1.7.

Comment: Doesn't work for IE8, Here is the error details  - Message: 'value' is null or not an object, Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @VishwaKumar Working fine at my end, I think might be happening due to some other cause!

Comment: Finally got it working in IE. The error was happening because i had an extra 'comma' at the end of the 'names' array. Might be helpful to someone. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you better to use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). It's simple to use and user - friendly solution

Comment: @vincuis: requirement was if the provided value not available in list then their should be an option to add new one their, provided link is good for multi select only but for along with adding new one is not.

Comment: Chosen looks very similar to select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).  I'd suggest select2 over that as it is just as simple and has many more options, as well as tagging support that lets you either autocomplete from a list, or enter your own.